# Extracting content from <![CDATA []]>

Tags: jquery, xml, cdata

I am having a string like:

```
"<![CDATA [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://www.google.com">consectetur</a> siptum. adipiscing elit. Phasellus pulvinar hendrerit malesuada. Mauris eget ante nulla. Suspendisse tempus lorem id.]]>"
```

using jquery I need to extract the entire content which is inside the `<![CDATA []]>`.
consider the entire data to be stored in a string variable.
Please help me with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with CDATA with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652159/parsing-xml-with-cdata-with-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with pure javascript, using substring:

```
var cDataString = "<![CDATA [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">consectetur</a> siptum. adipiscing elit. Phasellus pulvinar hendrerit malesuada. Mauris eget ante nulla. Suspendisse tempus lorem id.]]>";
cDataString = cDataString.substring(0, (cDataString.length - 3)); // remove ]]>
cDataString = cDataString.substring(10, (cDataString.length)); // remove <![CDATA [
alert(cDataString);
```

Comment: This does not address the question.