# Read text inside of CDATA using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, cdata

It gives me blanks instead of "Strengthened leadership in Poland and in Portugal" text when i am trying to get text inside of CDATA from  tag using below code?

**Code:**

```
var story = item.getElementsByTagName("HighLightedResume").item(0).text;
```

My XML is as below:

```
<Items>
<Item>
<HighLightedResume><![CDATA[Strengthened leadership in Poland and in Portugal]]></HighLightedResume>
</Item>
</Items>
```

Comment: already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652159/parsing-xml-with-cdata-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks Brij..but there was to much said and i am not able to understand that...Can you please indicate directly what is missing in my code?

Comment: I have also tried to send response by settings xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'text/xml'); but still getting same result..

Comment: You are basically saying *"The other thread contains too much text so I did not read it. Please write down the code for me."* Think about that for a moment.